# In flutter if i want to put height 10px or 10% so how should i used it?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

**Any type of height, width, top, left, right, etc.. needs px OR %(percentage)  so how can I use it.
it can be a Container, Padding, SizeBox, etc.. widget.**

```
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0), //need 10px or 10%, so how to use ?
```

Comment: The one that you are using is for padding. What is exactly are you trying to achieve here? Could your please elaborate more.

Comment: To get the screen height you can use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, then simply divide it by 10 to get 10% of the total height. Keep in mind that this updates the Widget so if you are gonna call it often then try storing it as a variable.

Comment: @SlowDeep thanks but if i want is to PX ?

Comment: @LalremLianBTlung thanks  -> i want to give a container height and width in PX or percentage like height = 10px, Or 10% .. so how can i used it

Comment: try : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0

Answer (score 1):

Use the [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) Class to get the current size of the window, as recommended by the official documentation.

> Querying the current media using MediaQuery.of will cause your widget
> to rebuild automatically whenever the MediaQueryData changes (e.g., if
> the user rotates their device).

```
margin: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .10 //To get the 10%
```

or

```
margin: 10.0 //To set 10px
```

---

If you want to get the size of only a single Widget, use [MediaQueryData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package.

After adding **Sizer package** to your project.

You may use **10.h** to get 10% of the height.

```
margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.h)
```

Comment: just use 10, it is 10px in flutter.

Comment: you may also use 10.sp using Sizer package and it would return screen pixel (sp) to you.

Answer (score 0):

no need to install additional packages, this can be achieved with standard flutter

```
double screenWidth = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window).size.width;

double screenHeight = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(WidgetsBinding.instance!.window).size.height;

margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: screenHeight * 0.1)
```